# Having trouble using jquery to click on a link

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm just trying to click on a link with jquery.  Here's my code.  When I click on the link manually it works, so I know the link is good.

```
$(this).find("td:first > * > a").click();
```

The error I get is Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

I can change the code to

```
$(this).find("td:first > * > a").css('background-color', "red");
```

and it changes the link background color to red so I know I've successfully selected the anchor.  I've researched a lot and found some others having issues with the `click()` function on links.

Here is a very simple jsfiddle of what I'm trying to do and I can't get it to work.   jsfiddle.net/vtLq9/10  When I click the button I want the link to be clicked and be taken to href.  Thanks.

Thanks for the help.

Dale

Comment: I've made it work using: window.location = $(this).find("td:first > * > a").attr("href");  Is this the preferred way to do this?

Comment: In your current code, you're only accessing the `click` function, you're not calling it. Use `.click()` rather than just `.click`.

Comment: I fixed that in the post.  It was just a typo in my post.  THanks.

Comment: Seems like this error happens when you have too big arrays or when functions recurse. It's not like you're having crazy a lot of links that are being clicked at the same time?

Comment: Here's a simple jsfiddle of what I'm trying to do.  http://jsfiddle.net/vtLq9/10/   When I click on the button I want the link to be clicked.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded` occurs when your call stack is too deep. This usually means you're calling a function that keeps call itself, possibly via another function.

There must be something else on the page that is interacting with this script. Does your click handler execute the click handle by any chance? ;)

Comment: There's only 1 link.  If I remove the click and replace it with the css function, I get no errors and the css function works.  So it's not choking on retrieving the anchor, it's just dying on the click() function.

Answer (score 0):

Dale,

Changing your code to use:

```
window.location = $(this).find("td:first > * > a").attr("href");
```

is not the preferred way to do this. It would bypass all other event listeners that would have been called and it assumes the link has an absolute path.